# Convert Fixed format Rpg code to free format

Tags: rpgle

Hi I need to convert fixed format code to Free format as per my companies coding standard instructions. I dont even understand what the below means except that some date movement and conversions are happening..

```
C     *ISO          MOVE      BCEXDT        MDYDATE
C                   MOVE      MDYDATE       PEXPDATT
C     *ISO          MOVE      BCSTDT        MDYDATE  
C                   MOVE      MDYDATE       PSTRDAT
```

Field definitions below:

```
BCEXDT         8S 0  
BCSTDT         8S 0
D  MDYDATE        S               D   DATFMT(*MDY)
```

Comment: Still need definitions for `PEXPDATT` and `PSTRDAT`.

Answer (score 5):

The two move operations for which you have shown the definitions can be converted like this:

```
C     *ISO          MOVE      BCEXDT        MDYDATE
C     *ISO          MOVE      BCSTDT        MDYDATE
```

to

```
MDYDate = %date(bcexdt: *ISO);
MDYDate = %date(bcstdt: *ISO);
```

Note that MDYDate is a date field, and has the same internal format as every other date field. The DATFMT(*MDY) keyword only defines how the field is represented externally by default when loaded into (or from) a character or numeric field. It also sets limits on allowable values. In the case of *MDY, those limits are `01-01-1940` to `12-31-2039`. Notice that the values in `BCEXDT` and `BCSTDT` are `*ISO` format, and the values limits are different for those fields. Specifically `0001-01-01` to `9999-12-31`. So you could get errors when attempting to assign the `*ISO` date to a `*MDY` date field.

The two moves I haven't converted for you would be done in one of the following ways.

1. If the targets are date fields:

```
pexpdatt = MDYDate;
pstrdat = MDYDate;
```

2. If the targets are numeric fields:

```
pexpdatt = %dec(MDYDate);
pstrdat = %dec(MDYDate);
```

3. If the targets are character fields:

```
pexpdatt = %char(MDYDate);
pstrdat = %char(MDYDate);
```

`%dec()` and `%char()` will assign the date fields in `*MDY` format since it was not explicitly specified in the assignment, and the date fields have `DATFMT(*MDY)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else is going to be able to tell you what is going on either; without the definitions of the source and target fields.

That's why IBM depreciated the `MOVE` op-code from free-form.

Comment: Field definition provided now.